# Joomla search modules for different categories of content

Tags: search, joomla, module, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I need at my site two different search modules.

The first module searches by categories such as 1 and 2, and the second searches by categories 3 and 4.

Can this be done using the standard search module with some modifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/16381